# Total number of days between 2 prompted dates (SAP Business Object Intelligent Rich Client)

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

i'm currnetly working on a BO project for a company in the health care field.

Basically, the user is prompted to enter an arrival and departure date, then a table is generated with all the patients that had a stay for at least one day within the arrival/departure date interval.

Then, I want to be able to count how many days the patient stayed during the interval.

For example :

Arrival date : 01/02/2019
Departure date : 10/02/2019

Patient A : from 01/01/2019 to 02/03/2019 will return 10 days (because arrival date =< prompted arrival date and departure date >= prompted departure date so we calculate the days between 01/02/2019 and 10/02/2019)

Patient B : from 05/02/2019 to 15/02/2019 will return 5 days (because arrival date >= prompted arrival date and departure date >= prompted departure date so we calculate the days between 05/02/2020 and 10/02/2019)

Patient C : from 25/01/2019 to 02/02/2019 will return 2 days (because arrival date =< prompted arrival date and 02/02/2020 =< prompted departure date so we calculate the days between 01/02/2019 and 02/02/2019)

[Here is my BO table :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJPsz.png)

I'm pretty sure my explanations are confusing, if you need any clarifications do not hesitate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to create two variables.

```
AdjustedArrivalDate=If([PatientArrivalDate]>=[PromptArrivalDate];[PatientArrivalDate];[PromptArrivalDate])

AdjustedDepartureDate=If([PatientDepartureDate]<=[PromptDepartureDate];[PatientDepartureDate];[PromptDepartureDate])
```

Then find the difference using the **DaysBetween** function.

```
StayDurationWithinPromptedRange=DaysBetween([AdjustedArrivalDate]; [AdjustedDepartureDate]) + 1
```

Comment: Working fine with your answer. Thank you!

Comment: Glad that worked for you. Kindly mark my answer as correct.